# build.gradle dependency results in compile error

Tags: android-studio, dependencies, build.gradle

After a long time, I have updated my Android Studio environment to the latest versions, but now my project doesn't compile anymore.

The error message displayed says

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.4.2-5326820. Searched
>   in the following locations:
>     - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.4.2-5326820/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820.pom
>     - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.4.2-5326820/aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows.jar
>   Required by:
>       project :app

The only reference there is to 3.4.2 is in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
}
```

but if I remove this, the project doesn't compile either.

Any hint on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding `google()` as a repository under `allprojects` in the build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```